# How can I remove punctuation at the end of a word in python?

Tags: python-3.x

How do I remove the last punctuation mark at the end of a word only in python. I have tried this but it removes all the punctuation marks. The solution should not remove any other characters that are not punctuation. 
 `word = "".join([i for i in word if i.isalpha()])`

Comment: `word = word[:-1] + (word[-1] if word[-1].isalpha() else '')`?

Answer (score 2):

You can just strip the punctuations

```
import string

words = ['apple.', 'banana;', 'coconut', 'date!']

print([w.strip(string.punctuation) for w in words])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all special character from string then you can try following code

```
import re
text = "your string"
text = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', text)
```